# include.path in .gitconfig works locally but not over SSH

Tags: git, ssh, windows-10

I'm running git on Windows on my work machine. My `%USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig` contains the following:

```
[include]
    path = .shared_gitconfig
```

I have another file `%USERPROFILE%\.shared_gitconfig` with some configuration settings inside. This works fine when running git on the machine itself:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Path\To\Repo> git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

However when I connect to the machine remotely using SSH, I get an error message when I try to use git:

```
user@PC:~$ ssh RemotePC
user@RemotePC C:\Users\User> cd Path\To\Repo
user@RemotePC C:\Users\User\Path\To\Repo> git status
fatal: bad config line 2 in file C:/Users/User/.gitconfig
```

Did something change recently in how git resolves `include.path`? It's supposed to resolve relative paths in the same directory as the original `.gitignore`.

Comment: No, `include.path` hasn't changed here. But note that *shared mounts* may not work the same if you remotely log in. See, e.g., https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/139 - when you use ssh you get a different login session which can have different network drive mappings.

Comment: I completely overlooked that my `.shared_gitconfig` was in fact a symlink to a file in the WSL (mounted on `\\wsl$` locally). So this remapping likely explains the issue.